# Find pattern and replace to another pattern string

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to check if string contains some patterns string For example: '4+3+6**4'.

I want replace the pattern `**` to `pow(x,y)`.

so i want the string will be `4+3+pow(6,4)`.

i want to know if there any way by 'Regex'.

trt.

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: When you say `pwo`, do you mean `pow`?

Comment: Do you also want to count the `pow(6,4)` so that the output is `4+3+1296`, or just leave it as a string?

Comment: @trt: If I were you, I'd mark as correct the answer with correct output, and the one that was provided first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture the number which exists before and after to `**` along with the match `**` and then replace the match with `pwo($1,$2)` .

```
Regex.Replace(string, @"(\d+)\*\*(\d+)", "pwo($1,$2)");
```

Comment: I guess you should have edited your answer rather than the question in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+)\*{2}(\d+)
```

You can use this.Replace by `pow($1,$2)`.See demo.Use verbatim mode `@`.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/15